# how to transaction replace a fragment in tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Android tabs with 3 fragments and a FAB. I want to replace to a new fragment when click the FAB but when i click the button it replace with a blank fragment. And when i click on my tabs, it doesn't show its fragment but an empty fragment instead (sometimes it show right but i don't know when)

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private FloatingActionButton fabAdd;
    FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pageAdapter.addFragment(new Wallet(), "Wallet");
        pageAdapter.addFragment(new History(),"History");
        pageAdapter.addFragment(new Setting(),"Setting");

        mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AddAccount addAccount = new AddAccount();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container,addAccount);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my adapter:

```
public class AccountAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private List<Account> accountList;

    public AccountAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Account> accountList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.accountList = accountList;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return accountList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(layout,null);

        TextView accountName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAccount);
        TextView accountAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);

        Account account = accountList.get(i);
        accountName.setText(account.getAccountName());
        accountAddress.setText(account.getAccountAddress());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is one of my Fragments (the other is same):

```
public class AddAccount extends Fragment {
    public AddAccount() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_account,container,false);
    }
}
```

I'm new to Android and not good English, so forgive me if i make grammar mistake.

Edit: Is there any way to show a new fragment to a viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside onClick

```
Fragment fragment = new AddAccount();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

and use this for your adapter

```
class AccountAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not work. Can you explain the idea or solution for this? I can't understand with your code only